# While creating a Gradle project one extra lib is creating as shown in the image. How to avoid that one?

Tags: gradle

While I am creating a Gradle project one extra lib (which I am highlighting) is creating as shown in the image

[image]

How to avoid that one?

Comment: How did you create this Gradle project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.